# How do I change visible part of the text in a (short) QLineEdit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

In my PyQt GUI, I've got a couple of relatively short (readOnly) QLineEdits containing some text. As the contained text is longer than the widget itself, only part of it can be shown. The QLineEdit widget typically shows the last part (by default):

[image]

As the figure shows, I'd like to make the first part of the text visible (by default). How do I do that?

I have added some code below to help you to setup a test-case quickly. Just copy-paste the code into a `*.py` file, run it, and you should get a QLineEdit in a window.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


'''================================================================================'''
'''|                           CUSTOM MAIN WINDOW                                 |'''
'''================================================================================'''
class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()

        # -------------------------------- #
        #           Window setup           #
        # -------------------------------- #

        # 1. Define the geometry of the main window
        # ------------------------------------------
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("QLineEdit test")

        # 2. Create frame and layout
        # ---------------------------
        self.__frm = QFrame(self)
        self.__frm.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: #ffffff }")
        self.__lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__lyt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.__frm.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__frm)

        # 3. Create QLineEdit
        # -------------------
        self.__myQLineEdit = QLineEdit("This is a very long line")
        self.__myQLineEdit.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.__myQLineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__myQLineEdit)


        self.show()

'''=== end Class ==='''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

''''''
```

---

Last but not least, I'd like to describe my system for completeness:

- Windows 10, 64-bit
- Python 3.6
- PyQt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the cursor position on various events, such as when the line-edit widget loses focus:

```
class CustomLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, txt, parent=None):
        super(CustomLineEdit, self).__init__(txt, parent)
        self.setCursorPosition(0)

    def focusOutEvent(self, e):
        self.setCursorPosition(0)
```

and possibly other events, such as when the selection changes, if you want.

Comment: Great, this works! What do you mean by "other events, such as when the selection changes"? How would that behave?

Comment: It is possible to scroll by selecting text and extending the selection towards the invisible portion of the text. If you want to prevent that, connect the `selectionChanged()` signal to a slot which does the same thing (`self.setCursorPosition(0)`).

Comment: @fferri in my case custom `QLineEdit` still had a hidden left part of text but according to `focusOutEvent` it changed when focus was out. Left part became visible. However I had multiple generated `QLineEdit` and when focus is out cursor still remaind in line. In my case solution was firstly to set text to widget and then `setCursorPosition(0)`.